# preg_match for dots,space or tabs

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

given

```
$str=array( "Chelsea 0-5 MAN-UNITED",
            "Chelsea 0-2 Aston Villa",
            "Chelsea 0-3 Pokemon (TRASH i dont want)");
```

output im trying to reach:

```
array(
    array('teams'=>'chelsea Vs MAN-UNITED','score'=>'0-5')
    array('teams'=>'chelsea Vs Aston Villa','score'=>'0-2')
    array('teams'=>'chelsea Vs Pokemon','score'=>'0-3')
    );
```

my current approach is by using explode(' ',$str); and then move [0].' Vs '.[2] into teams and [1] into score..

that is working fine except when there is a whitespace inside team name, or when there is extra text inside ().

so can this be done using preg_match ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str=array( "Chelsea 0-5 MAN-UNITED",
            "Chelsea 0-2 Aston Villa",
            "Chelsea 0-3 Pokemon (TRASH i dont want)");


$arr = array();

$pattern = "/([0-9]+\-[0-9]+)/";
foreach ($str as $sub) {
    $parts = preg_split($pattern, $sub, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    if (count($parts) == 3) {
        $team1 = trim(preg_replace("/\(.*\Z/", "", $parts[0]));
        $score = trim($parts[1]);
        $team2 = trim(preg_replace("/\(.*\Z/", "", $parts[2]));

        $teams = "$team1 Vs $team2";

        $element = array("teams" => $teams, "score" => $score);
        $arr[] = $element;
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Input:

```
$str=array( "Chelsea 0-5 MAN-UNITED",
        "Chelsea 0-2 Aston Villa",
        "Chelsea 0-3 Pokemon (TRASH i dont want)");
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [teams] => Chelsea Vs MAN-UNITED
            [score] => 0-5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [teams] => Chelsea Vs Aston Villa
            [score] => 0-2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [teams] => Chelsea Vs Pokemon
            [score] => 0-3
        )

)
```

Here it is in action: http://eval.in/14236

Oh, and make sure you're using at least PHP 4.0.5. That's when `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` was introduced.

Comment: exactly what i wanted :).. thanks alot, i would love to understand more about writing patterns for preg_match, can you teach me a bit about them ?!

Comment: I have a 2cm-thick book on my desk in front of me right now. RegEx is a huge standard, and there's a ton you can do with it. My suggestion would be to look for a tutorial online and go from there. Oh, and there's a neat tool online called RegExr, where you can play around with pattern matching. Here's one that matches your question above: http://regexr.com?34bvu

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
preg_split('/ (\d+-\d+) /', $str, 3, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

This will put the three segments that you want into an array.  In your first example above:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(8) "Chelsea"
  [1] =>
  string(3) "0-5"
  [2] =>
  string(11) "MAN-UNITED"
}
```

You can then further filter the 1st and 3rd results to remove trash.  Unfortunately, you haven't given specific rules for handling trash.  If there can be trash between a team and a score, it may be pretty difficult to get it out unless you know what you are looking for.  I'm also not sure whether `\d+-\d+` can appear anywhere in the string other than the score.

Another possibility is

```
preg_match('/([a-z\.\s]+)(\d+-\d+)([a-z\.\s]+)/i', $str, $matches);
```

...which stores the three items in `$matches` and gets rid of trash.  However, it doesn't allow for numbers in team names and doesn't trim the trailing/leading whitespace.

Comment: Same. I'll leave mine up, since it handles the garbage parentheses. But you got my +1.